# My foobar2000 stays invisible. How to show it?

Tags: windows-7, foobar2000

Each time I start foobar2000 on my Windows 7, the application launches (as sound goes by my speakers), but no icon shows, nor on the taskbar, neither in the icon notification area. How can I change that ?

Comment: Because you did not tell us all the things you tried and did not work, you get my low end comment :-)  first Foobar itself try | Preferences | Columns UI | Status bar | systray | minimize to tray |, because it can be turned off there.  Then Hover over the Windows notification tray Clock  right click and select | Customise Notification Icons |  at the bottom select  | Always Show All Icons and Notifications | <--- this is temporary for insuring nothing is missed for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I was not able to edit foobar2000 preferences, I ended up shutting it down through task manager, then delete the config files for column_ui. Not clean, neither cool (as its UI is now messed up), but nevertheless efficient, as foobar2000 shows up nicely now.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few thinks you can try:

- Disable aero theme or switch to classic theme and start foobar2000.
- Run foobar2000 as administrator
- Open task manager and see if you can 'Switch To' or 'Bring to front' foobar2000.
- reinstall foobar2000 as administrator.

Good luck with it!

Greetings,
Mixxiphoid

PS: If you found the solution please post it!

Comment: It may also be the case that Foobar2000's window is positioned off-screen. Hold the Windows key and press the left or right arrow key and see if Windows snaps the window to one side of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

**Same issue resolved by using A. Lambert's [Windows Key + Left Arrow] suggestion.**

---

Snapped the window to the left side of the screen and then I dragged it to the middle of the screen. No clue where it was positioned but that reset it. Closed and reopened to make sure. Thanks :)

Stuff I tried first:

- Alt+Tab,
- Task Manager/Users/(Username Dropdown)/Right-click foobar/Select "Switch To",
- Right-click systray icon to open Preferences dialog box

Answer (score 1):

How can I minimise Foobar player into system tray.
There are 2 variants:

**1.** File **>** Preferences **>** Default user interface **-** *Minimize to notification area*;

**2.** File **>** Display **>** Columns UI **-** *Minimise to icon*.

- Possible problem: With the 1st variant you will need to install Columns UI.
- P.S. Yes, I understand that it will not help your problem, but this page showed up when I googled some advice on how to minimise Foobar into system tray. Now it hides there without showing its minimised window in taskbar, which saves some space.